# Transforming a queryset to get the most recent entry, per name

Tags: python, django

My data looks like this:

```
class Entry(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    size = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

If I do:

```
qs = Entry.objects.all()
```

I get a `queryset` with all entries. How would I transform that `queryset` to get *another queryset*  with the most recent entry *per name*?

Comment: What is your database backend?

Comment: You could probably do that with [subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Thanks! I have no experience with subqueries and do not know where to start. Do you have an example which could be used as a starting point for my usecase?

Comment: Only the one on that docs page I link to. I tend to take that and play around until it works.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: db backend is postgres, by am looking for a django-ORM based solution

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this I guess :

```
qs = Entry.objects.values('name').annotate(Max('date')).order_by()
```

You have to import `Max` previously.

I didn't try my queryset, but it should work.

Comment: This fails with: `Cannot call only() after .values() or .values_list()`

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using a postgres backend, you can use [`distinct(*fields)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) in combination with an appropriate `order_by`:

```
qs = Entry.objects.all()
qs = qs.order_by('name', '-date').distinct('name')
```